# WATSON Q and A base URL

Tags: ibm-watson

Thanks in advance.  We had one of the original beta accounts for accessing IBMs WATSON and recently re-activated the account. I am probably looking right at the answer and missing it, but I do not see the base URL in the documentation and the original base URL does not appear to be working. Originally we were connecting with https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/qagw/service/v1/question
Can someone point me in the right direction within the online documentation?

VLG

Answer (score 1):

The Question and Answer service url is:

```
https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/question-and-answer-beta/api
```

You will need a `username` and `password`, you can get them from bluemix.net

Take a look at the Swagger docs to learn about the API.
The service has currently two corpus (healthcare and travel).

Demo: http://question-and-answer-demo.mybluemix.net/

Comment: Thanks for the help, I wlll review the docs you have suggested

VLG